Installing programs on a secondary ssd
I read that if i have 2 ssd drives, that it is a good idea to have the operating system on 1 ssd and installed files on another ssd
The reason that they gave is that, if the operating system gets corrupted, any files I installed should be safe.
My question is...
Windows has different folders for installs, for example on a 64 bit system, there will be program files for 64 bit software and program files x86 for 32 bit software.
When installing on a separate ssd, is it important to create the same folder structure?

Advice seems bad. Use full drive image to back up all: operating system, installed Windows apps and applications, and data. As for moving files to make room on the OS drive. it's easy to  move Documents, Music, Photos and Videos, but it's not easy to move applications.

It's not so much moving applications. I'm more talking about installing them. If I install on the secondary ssd

Clearly not recommended.

While it is possible to install applications to locations other than the primary drive, this is generally NOT recommended because that is a complex process that generally results in things not behaving as expected. If you do this you will need to continually be aware of this fact and you will have to regularly adjust default application processes and settings to account for this non-standard location.
The advice you received was bad advice and I don't think I've every seen someone recommend that before, but...
What is better advice, and what good sources may actually advise, is to place your data, personal files and the like, on the second drive.
However, this isn't really a factor of speed or retaining data so much as it is about space, and so you really only should do this if you're running low on space.
If you work in media creation, for instance, keeping your large media files on a secondary drive is usually a good idea, to keep space clear on the OS drive.
But, if you aren't running out of space on the primary drive, and you aren't planning to take up work that will use up your space quickly, there is little reason to have a secondary drive except for local backup purposes.
